# How to create global variables once when app is launched in Go?

Tags: go, caching, encryption

Good day for all readers!

I have api service which needs key for some decrypt issues. Key calculates all time when I make request. That is wrong from an architectural point of view.

The option with environments (.env, viper...) drops because, in the future, I want to bring out this module to a separate library.

Hint me, how it is possible without using environments to calculate the key when starting the application and use it until stopping the application?

Comment: Have a package level variable (global variable) to store the key, you may use a package `init()` function to calculate / initialize it. Although it's better to not have "global" variables, it's better to have some kind of application context where you can store global state.

Comment: I know, but if it would be library, then this wouldn't be good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global var starts with a capital, so it is reachable from within other packages.

But... it's actually bad behaviour, because those other packages can change it.

Having a non capital one, still means that functions in the same package can change it.

Perhaps you can use a constant?
or make a singleton variable, see :

https://goplay.tools/snippet/9k7FLYbbvoo

Comment: Thank you for advise using singleton pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you need a global variable, you can do this:

```golang
package main

var globalVar string = "My string"

func init(){
    globalVar = "The new value of the variable"
}

func main(){
    println(globalVar)
}
```